# Mesh Detection works only after I have opened Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection, mesh, developer-tools

I load some obj. and .mtl files and I create and add some object in the scene. I put them in an array, so I can detect when they 're clicked succesfully. ( (intersectObjects(objs,true) )

Although, when I create simple circle meshes and put them in an array so I can detect them, detection does not fully work. Very difficultly intersectObjects() detects my clicks on the circles (needs 4-5 clicks on average).

The strange thing is that when I press F12 and I open the Developer Tools (and then I close it or not,does not matter), everything works perfectly and the circles are easily detected. Very strange. I think something is wrong with intersectObjects(). It seems to me that it does not handle well the meshes.

Piece of code (because project is big and complicated):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100222836/code.js

Note: I think couple of days ago console put out an "error" message relate to the .getDescendants function of the Three.js file in the IntersectObjects function.

**EDIT**

**An other odd thing that happens is that before I open the developer tools, I click next to a circle ( the empty space at the left of a circle) and it detects the click as if I had clicked the circle itself (the circle in the right of the empty space changes color as expected by the click)! (see pic where I click :** https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gqb6iovon8c665/Screenshot%202014-05-15%2015.51.18.png ).

**After I opened the Tools, it does not detect the clicking in the empty space at the left of a circle. Instead, I click on a circle and it detects the click as if I had done it in the right circle* (the circle in the right of the one I clicked, changes color as expected by the click) : [https://www.dropbox.com/s/ntiumegrg7wkgie/Screenshot%202014-05-15%2015.51](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ntiumegrg7wkgie/Screenshot%202014-05-15%2015.51.18%20-%20Copy.png)**.18%20-%20Copy.png

So Something is wrong with the meshes that are loaded on the scene, or with how the intersect() works.**

*I fixed that,it was just a math problem. So now when I open the D.T. it works fine. Still remains the problem if I don't open the D.T.

**

- EDIT 2 this is the code of the project. check it : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100222836/test.html

**

Comment: I understand the project is big and you can't share it, but can you do a small/separate test with the basics?

Comment: I will try to make a jsfiddle. till then, I will add an EDIT to the post above because a friend observed an other anomaly in the app. I think it is an important clue.

Comment: found the solution, I had changes the camera's aspect because I changed the width and the height to fit the canvas and the div better in the screen.

Comment: No need to delete the question. He could answer his own question. I actually had a feeling that that was what was going on.